# Images are not visible?

Tags: image, cache

all new to Magento, but just trying to see if it will work for me:

I've just installed Magento **via Installatron** with sample data.
The shop works but images are not visible. Even when I upload an image in the backend it is not visible in the frontend.

When I enter the link of the image in a new page I get this error: 
`"The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request"` or via this [link](http://www.domeintest.eu/shop/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/135x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/n/o/nokia-2610-phone-2.jpg)

I didn't change the settings of the files or directories, because there are no files or directories to change. It is a **new** install. Link to [shop](http://www.domeintest.eu/shop)

**Could this be an issue with the provider or with Installatron?**

Regards, Peter

Comment: check the permission of media folder

Comment: Please clear all the cache in the Magento admin including your image cache. Also make sure the permissions on your media folder a set to o+w

Answer (score 1):

I believe your file permissions for the files and directories under "/media" is set incorrectly.

If your server is running on suPHP or suEXEC, do make sure that under the "/media" directory, all files should be set to 644 and all directories to 755.

If the server is not running suPHP or suEXEC, all files under the "/media" directory should be set to 666 and all directories to 777.